# Class diagram for xpages project

Tags: relational-database, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, class-diagram

I am working on a project with Xpages.I wanted to know how to make the representation of a class diagram to my project.Notes is a documentary database so no relationnal.How I could represent my entities?

Answer (score 4):

In Domino, documents are merely evidence of the existence of people, processes, and physical entities (products, offices, inventory, etc.). Ideally, your classes should model those things.

For instance, you might have classes like `Employee`, with properties like `firstName`, `lastName`, `hireDate`; maybe `Asset`, with properties like `category`, `model`, `serialNumber`; or perhaps `Request`, with properties like `status`, `requester`, `dateApproved`. Eventually the values of each of these properties might be stored as item values in Domino documents, but defining these first as attributes of classes allows you to follow a simple pattern to develop your application:

1. Use your class structure to rapidly define the nature of each "thing" your application interacts with, without worrying yet what each must look like or how and where the data will ultimately be stored.
2. Once you have these classes defined, you can bind visual components on an XPage (such as input fields like edit boxes and radio button groups) very easily using the `#{dataSource.propertyName}` syntax.
3. When these two steps are done, all you have left to do is to add two methods to each of these entity classes: one to write the data, and another to retrieve it.

Following this approach makes it very easy to rapidly build the application, but also protects your user interface from changes in how you wish the data to be stored. Initially, each object might represent a single document. As the application grows in either complexity or adoption, however, you may decide to segregate the data such that many documents are created to represent a single entity. Or at some point you might even decide to store some, or all, of the data outside of Domino (DB2, SQL, etc.). If your XPage components are bound to properties of these entity classes, all you need to do to change how or where the data is stored is to update the two methods you created in step 3 of the above list: alter how you write and retrieve the data. Your actual XPage design elements don't need to change at all.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you look at it. You can always think of following relation: Notes Form <-> Java POJO and Notes View <-> Java Collections.

See http://www.pipalia.co.uk/notes-development/rethinking-xpages-part-two/ for some tips on using Java world standards when working with xPages.